# Lexicographic Quick Sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I try to sort an array of `Strings` in lexicographical order by using the quick sort algorithm in java. The array is read in via the terminal using a `Scanner` and saved in an `ArrayList`. This `ArrayList` is later converted to an array where I (try to) apply the quick sort algorithm on.
I have two methods:

```
private static void sortA(String[] s, int start, int end) {
    if (end > start) {
        int pivot = partition(s, start, end);
        sortA(s, start, pivot - 1);
        sortA(s, pivot + 1, end);
    }
}

private static int partition(String[] s, int start, int end) {
    String pivot = s[end];
    int left = start;
    int right = end;
    String temp = "";
    do {
        while ((s[left].compareTo(pivot) <= 0) && (left < end))
            left++;
        while ((s[right].compareTo(pivot) > 0) && (right > start))
            right--;
        if (left < right) {
            temp = s[left];
            s[left] = s[end];
            s[right] = temp;
            printRow(s);

        }
    } while (left < right);
    temp = s[left];
    s[left] = s[end];
    s[end] = temp;
    return left;
}
```

The code seems to randomly work fine and then suddenly not. For example the array `{"java", "application", "system"}` sorts fine to `{"application", "java", "system"}`. The array `{"library", "content", "bin"}` sorts to `{"bin", "library", "contents"}`, which is not the lexicographic order. Of course a computer does not work randomly so there must be something wrong with my code. I tried to work out an example on paper but then I'll find something completely wrong. However I based my code on an quick sort implementation of sorting a double array so I don't think I made a big reasoning error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the array in the wrong way:
The correct splitting is "pivot-1" "pivot"

```
sortA(s, start, pivot-1);
sortA(s, pivot, end);
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it works now. Such a stupid mistake I made... I accept the answer as soon as possible!